# SOAP client causes 500 or 502 error with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm having problems with SOAP on a new dedicated server. Scripts are working very well on our stage server but when I try the functions from live site It just doesn't work.

The script creates a soap instance and then sends some info to a tracking company.

The live server we are using is brand new and a centOS is installed. I installed php-pear and soap using yum install but nothing changed.

If I run php with CGI or Fast CGI , I just get 500 Internal error but if I run it with Apache module I get 502 Bad Gateway error with ngix, below is a sample from the testing code. I would appreciate if you could help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//echo (dirname(__FILE__));
require_once('soap-wsa.php');
require_once('soap-wsse.php');

class mySoap extends SoapClient {
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $doc->loadXML($request);

        $objWSA = new WSASoap($doc);
        $objWSA->addAction($saction);
        $objWSA->addTo($location);
        $objWSA->addMessageID();
        $objWSA->addReplyTo();

        $doc = $objWSA->getDoc();

        $objWSSE = new WSSESoap($doc);

        /* add Timestamp with no expiration timestamp */
        $objWSSE->addTimestamp();
        $objWSSE->addUserToken('xxx','xxxxx',TRUE);
        return parent::__doRequest($objWSSE->saveXML(), $location, $saction, $version);
    }

}

$wsdl_base = 'http://stage.xxxx.com/SmartLeadImport/';

$wsdl   = $wsdl_base.'SmartLeadImport.asmx?wsdl';
$to     = $wsdl_base.'SmartLeadImport.asmx';
$action = $wsdl_base.'Lookup_SAT';

$leadObject = array(
'Lead' => array(
    'Company' => 'Test',
    'LeadID' => array(
            'Type'  => 'Client',
            'Value' => '1234567'
        ),
    'Person' => array(
            'FirstName' => 'Test',
            'LastName'  => 'Testerson'
        )
)
);

echo '<pre>';
try {
$sClient = new mySoap($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
/* Force location path - MUST INCLUDE trailing slash
BUG in ext/soap that does not automatically add / if URL does not contain path cause POST header to be invalid */
$sClient->location = $to;
$sClient->saction  = $action;
$test              = $sClient->Lookup_SAT(array('SATCode' => 1));

print_r($test->Lookup_SATResult);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
print_r($e);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causing the problem.

At first Our server's time was wrong and I had fixed it, well I thought I fixed it but the think is that the server time should be synchronized with US Naval Observatory Master Clock Time

http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/simpletime.html

It allows only 3 minutes difference. Mine was 5 minutes. I have changed the server time and everything's good now.